# PHP Update mysql database after PHP script has been executed

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a php script and using mysql databases to make a sports picks website. The users will submit their picks into a mysql database, and based on whether those picks are right or wrong, I want to give them a certain score.

The problem is of course the users will be making these picks BEFORE each sporting event so I need a way to update the page after each event to score users based on the information(picks) they gave in the table. I have everything scripted out including a FUNCTION called `fun();` that would score users based on their picks.   I tested the script, and after I submitted my picks I tried to add `fun();` to the script and save it. The score table didn't update.

How can I update the PHP script? I hope all this makes sense. Here is the function code and the script I'm trying to add the function to.

Here is the Function. It tests pick1.

```
function fun()
{

  //loop declare begin
  $quer = "SELECT * FROM sffedorvsdan WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'";

  if($quer_run = mysql_query($quer))
  {
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($quer_run))
      {
        $pick1 = $row['pick1'];
        $pick2 = $row['pick2'];
        $pick3 = $row['pick3'];
        $pick4 = $row['pick4'];
        $pick5 = $row['pick5'];
        $pick6 = $row['pick6']; 

       //loop end EXCEPT CLOSE  

       $user = $_SESSION['username'];

        if($pick1 == '11')
        {

          $score = mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET score = (score + 10), mmascore = (mmascore + 10), wins = (wins + 1), games =(games + 1) WHERE username = '$user'");

          return $score;
        }

        else if($pick1 == '21')
        {    
           $score2 = mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET score = (score - 5), mmascore = (mmascore - 5), games = (games + 1) WHERE username = '$user'");

           return $score2;
        }
     }
  }else{
    echo mysql_error();
  }
}    
?>
```

Heres the main script including html and where I want fun(); to go. In the //Pick Start comments only pay attention to //Pick 1 Start as it's the only one I'm trying to test.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<?php

session_start();



if ($_SESSION['username'])
{

$connect2 = //WHERE I CONNECT TO DATABASE

$sql = "SELECT * FROM access WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'";

$query = mysql_query($sql,$connect2);

if ($query) {

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $activated = $row['sf'];

        if ($activated!='0')
        {
            die("You've already submitted your answers<br><a href='mmanav.php'>BACK</a>");
        }
    }
}
$user = "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['username']."!<br><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
}
else
{
    die("You must be logged in!");
}

//PICK VARIABLES
$dan_status = 'unchecked';
$fedor_status = 'unchecked';

$paul_status = 'unchecked';
$tyron_status = 'unchecked';

$tim_status = 'unchecked';
$robbie_status = 'unchecked';

$tarec_status = 'unchecked';
$scott_status = 'unchecked';

$marloes_status = 'unchecked';
$miesha_status = 'unchecked';

//function file
include('fun.php');
//function file end 



if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{

$connect = //WERE I CONNECT TO DATABASE



//PICK 1 START

$selected_radio = $_POST['fighter'];

if ($selected_radio == 'dan') 
{
$dan_status = 'checked';

mysql_query("INSERT INTO sffedorvsdan (id,username,pick1) VALUES ('','$_SESSION[username]','11')"); //insert table data picks


}
else if ($selected_radio == 'fedor') 
{
$fedor_status = 'checked';

mysql_query("INSERT INTO sffedorvsdan (id,username,pick1) VALUES ('','$_SESSION[username]','21')"); //insert table data picks


}

//PICK 2 START

$selected2_radio = $_POST['fighter2'];

if ($selected2_radio == 'paul') 
{
$paul_status = 'checked';

/*mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET score = (score + 10), mmascore = (mmascore + 10)
WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'");*/
}
else if ($selected2_radio == 'tyron') 
{
$tyron_status = 'checked';

/*mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET score = (score - 5), mmascore = (mmascore - 5)
WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'");*/
}

//PICK 3 START

$selected3_radio = $_POST['fighter3'];

if ($selected3_radio == 'tim') 
{
$tim_status = 'checked';

/*mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET score = (score + 10), mmascore = (mmascore + 10)
WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'");*/
}
else if ($selected3_radio == 'robbie') 
{
$robbie_status = 'checked';

/*mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET score = (score - 5), mmascore = (mmascore - 5)
WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'");*/
}

//PICK 4 START

$selected4_radio = $_POST['fighter4'];

if ($selected4_radio == 'tarec') 
{
$tarec_status = 'checked';

//mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET score = (score + 10), mmascore = (mmascore + 10)
//WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'");
}
else if ($selected4_radio == 'scott') 
{
$scott_status = 'checked';

//mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET score = (score - 5), mmascore = (mmascore - 5)
//WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'");
}

//PICK 5 START

$selected5_radio = $_POST['fighter5'];

if ($selected5_radio == 'marloes') 
{
$marloes_status = 'checked';

//mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET score = (score + 10), mmascore = (mmascore + 10)
//WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'");
}
else if ($selected5_radio == 'miesha') 
{
$miesha_status = 'checked';

//mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET score = (score - 5), mmascore = (mmascore - 5)
//WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'");
}



mysql_query("UPDATE access SET sf ='1'
WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'");

fun(); //WHERE FUN WILL GO AFTER I RUN THE SCRIPT ONCE

die("Your picks have been submitted!<br><a href='gamenav.php'>Return</a>");

}

?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="log">
<?php echo $user; ?>
</div>

<div class="logo">
<img src="IB SportsTV Logo.png" width="240px" height="180px"/>
</div>







<FORM name ="form" method ="POST" action ="picks.php">

<div class="mainform">

<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='fighter' value= 'dan' 
<?PHP print $dan_status; ?>
>Dan Henderson<br>
<img src="Dan_Henderson.jpg" width="100" height="100"/><br>


<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='fighter' value= 'fedor' 
<?PHP print $fedor_status; ?>
>Fedor Emelianenko<br>
<img src="Fedor_Emelianenko.png" width="100" height="100"/><br><br><br>

</div>


<div class="form2">

<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='fighter2' value= 'paul' 
<?PHP print $paul_status; ?>
>Paul Daley<br>
<img src="Paul_Daley.png" width="100" height="100"/><br>


<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='fighter2' value= 'tyron' 
<?PHP print $tyron_status; ?>
>Tyron Woodley<br>
<img src="Tyron_Woodley.jpg" width="100" height="100"/><br><br><br>

</div>


<div class="form3">

<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='fighter3' value= 'tim' 
<?PHP print $tim_status; ?>
>Tim Kennedy<br>
<img src="Tim_Kennedy.png" width="100" height="100"/><br>


<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='fighter3' value= 'robbie' 
<?PHP print $robbie_status; ?>
>Robbie Lawler<br>
<img src="Robbie_Lawler.png" width="100" height="100"/><br><br><br>

</div>


<div class="form4">

<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='fighter4' value= 'tarec' 
<?PHP print $tarec_status; ?>
>Tarec Saffiedine<br>
<img src="Tarec_Saffiedine.png" width="100" height="100"/><br>


<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='fighter4' value= 'scott' 
<?PHP print $scott_status; ?>
>Scott Smith<br>
<img src="Scott_Smith.png" width="100" height="100"/><br><br><br>

</div>


<div class="form5">

<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='fighter5' value= 'marloes' 
<?PHP print $marloes_status; ?>
>Marloes Coenen<br>
<img src="Marloes_Coenen.jpg" width="100" height="100"/><br>


<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='fighter5' value= 'miesha' 
<?PHP print $miesha_status; ?>
>Miesha Tate<br>
<img src="Miesha_Tate.png" width="100" height="100"/><br>

</div>


<div class="submitbutton">

<P>
<Input type = "Submit" Name = "submit" VALUE = "SUBMIT PICKS">
</FORM>

</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We are going to need to see some code to be able to help you out.

Comment: Remember, we have tags, so no need for the tags in the title. Also, consider using line breaks.

Comment: You've added some code, great! Where's the rest of it? Like where you call fun()? And where you connect to a database before trying to query one?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this line instead:

```
$quer = "SELECT * FROM sffedorvsdan WHERE username = '{$_SESSION['username']}'";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot going on there, so I think I'm just going to leave a general outline as to how I would handle this for a small website (a website with a large amount of traffic would include cache tables, cron jobs, and all sorts of funness):

1. User logs in and goes to that page.
2. Compare predictions for past events with the winners.
3. Calculate scores.
4. Display them.

My select statement might be (if the table `EVENTS` was for the events, and `PREDICTIONS` is for predictions)

```
SELECT SUM( WINS ) FROM (
    SELECT
       -- if they are correct, they will get 1, otherwise 0
       IF( EVENTS.WINNER = PREDICTIONS.CHOICE, 1, 0 ) AS WINS
    FROM
       -- since you need information from two tables, you need to use JOIN.
       EVENTS, PREDICTIONS
       -- assuming that EVENTS.ID and PREDICTIONS.EVENT_ID are related through
       -- something called a foreign key
       ON ( EVENTS.ID = PREDICTIONS.EVENT_ID )
    WHERE
       -- an entry in EVENTS should only have a winner if the event has passed
       -- so there is no need for a time calculation.
       -- ... unless someone is taking a dive... ;-)
       EVENTS.WINNER IS NOT NULL AND
       PREDICTIONS.USER_ID = 'userID' )
```

That query will mean that you can always have a current total which directly relates the user with his number of correct predictions. All he does is update the prediction. All you do is update the EVENTS.WINNER.

Actually, I would explicitly avoid storing the score without tracking this data as well -- if you have the raw, non-calculated data, you can always populate something based on it (such as my example).

Comment: Thanks! The logic here makes sense and I'll try to use this. The problem with my code comes when I try to update the winner after the user inputs their choice. I try to put my function "fun();" in the php script after the user submits their picks and it doesn't add the score. I just need to find out how to get that function to run.